# Convert nested JSON to simple JSON

Tags: c#, json, recursion, converters, traversal

I'm trying to convert a nested json to simple json by recursively traversing.
(Structure of input json is unknown)

for example, I want json like this

```
{
    "FirstName": "Rahul",
    "LastName": "B",
    "EmpType": {
        "RID": 2,
        "Title": "Full Time"
    },
    "CTC": "3.5",
    "Exp": "1",
    "ComplexObj": {
        "RID": 3,
        "Title": {
            "Test": "RID",
            "TWO": {
                "Test": 12
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to be converted something like this

```
{
    "FirstName": "Rahul",
    "LastName": "B",
    "EmpType__RID": 2,
    "EmpType__Title": "Full Time",
    "CTC": "3.5",
    "Exp": "1",
    "ComplexObj__RID": 3,
    "ComplexObj__Title__Test": "RID",
    "ComplexObj__Title__TWO__Test": 12
}
```

each fields in nested object will be changed to key which represents its actual path.

this is what I have done so far.

```
    public static void ConvertNestedJsonToSimpleJson(JObject jobject, ref JObject jobjectRef, string currentNodeName = "", string rootPath = "")
    {
        string propName = "";
        if (currentNodeName.Equals(rootPath))
        {
            propName = currentNodeName;
        }
        else
        {
            propName = (rootPath == "" && currentNodeName == "") ? rootPath + "" + currentNodeName : rootPath + "__" + currentNodeName;
        }

        foreach (JProperty jprop in jobject.Properties())
        {
            if (jprop.Children<JObject>().Count() == 0)
            {
                jobjectRef.Add(propName == "" ? jprop.Name : propName + "__" + jprop.Name, jprop.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                currentNodeName = jprop.Name;
                rootPath = rootPath == "" ? jprop.Name : rootPath;
                ConvertNestedJsonToSimpleJson(JObject.Parse(jprop.Value.ToString()), ref jobjectRef, currentNodeName, rootPath);
            }
        }
    }
```

and getting wrong result

```
{
    "FirstName": "Rahul",
    "LastName": "B",
    "EmpType__RID": 2,
    "EmpType__Title": "Full Time",
    "CTC": "3.5",
    "Exp": "1",
    "EmpType__ComplexObj__RID": 3,
    "EmpType__Title__Test": "RID",
    "EmpType__two__Test": 12
}
```

will appreciate any help on correcting my code, or any other approach to archive this.

Comment: are you using visual studio? If you attach a process to your program you should be able to see exactly what the issue is as you step through it

Comment: `rootPath = rootPath == "" ? jprop.Name : rootPath;` after the application execute this line of code for the first time the condition will be always false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You don't need to convert the value of the property to string and then parse it again every time - just cast it to `JObject`
- You don't need the complicated conditional logic to generate the name of the property - just use this: `prefix + jprop.Name + "__"`

The code:

```
public static void FlattenJson(JObject node, JObject result, string prefix = "")
{
    foreach (var jprop in node.Properties())
    {
        if (jprop.Children<JObject>().Count() == 0)
        {
            result.Add(prefix + jprop.Name, jprop.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            FlattenJson((JObject)jprop.Value, $"{prefix}{jprop.Name}__", result);
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var node = JObject.Parse(/* the input string */);
var result = new JObject();
FlattenJson(node, result);
```

Comment: Just an hint: `prefix + jprop.Name + "__"` in a more cleaner way is `$"{prefix }{jprop.Name}__"`

Comment: @Tinwor I'm not sure if it is cleaner in this case but it is definitely more succinct.

Comment: awesome code!! great to make a datatable from any json, to flatten also arrays:
if (jprop.Value.GetType() != typeof(JArray)) ... else {result.Add(prefix + "arr_" + jprop.Name, string.Join(",",jprop.Value));}

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is in the line `rootPath = rootPath == "" ? jprop.Name : rootPath;`. You are changing the rootPath when you first come across `EmpType` which means when you process `ComplexObj` your rootPath is wrong. What I believe you intended is just to change what you were passing into the recursive function.

As it is though it is unnecessary to keep track of root and currentnode as two separate items. Better would be to just track the current prefix for a given node in code that looks more like this:

```
public static void ConvertNestedJsonToSimpleJson(JObject input, JObject output, string prefix = "")
{
    foreach (JProperty jprop in input.Properties())
    {
        var name = prefix==""?jprop.Name:String.Format("{0}__{1}", prefix,jprop.Name);
        if (jprop.Children<JObject>().Count() == 0)
        {
            output.Add(name, jprop.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            ConvertNestedJsonToSimpleJson((JObject)jprop.Value, output, name);
        }
    }
}
```

This now gives me the output:

```
{
  "FirstName": "Rahul",
  "LastName": "B",
  "EmpType__RID": 2,
  "EmpType__Title": "Full Time",
  "CTC": "3.5",
  "Exp": "1",
  "ComplexObj__RID": 3,
  "ComplexObj__Title__Test": "RID",
  "ComplexObj__Title__TWO__Test": 12
}
```

which looks correct.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. It works fine for 2 levels nesting, the last field in output json should be 
"ComplexObj__Title__TWO__Test": 12

Comment: Ah yes. Looking at it I think its because the recursion is a bit of a mess in how it works (with the root and current node being passed around). I strongly suspect a fix to this code will end up looking like Botond's excellent concise rewrite of your code so I will refer you to his answer for now.

Comment: Have now updated my answer with simpler working code. Its not quite the same but very similar to Botond's.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this using linq

```
var jsonObj = jobject.select(x => new CustomJson {
   FirstName = x.FirstName,
   LastName = x.LastName,
   EmpTypeId = x.EmpType.Id,
   Title = x.EmpType.Title
   etc etc
});
```

Comment: Yes, I can do like this but my input json dynamic structure is unknown. Sorry haven't mentioned it previously, edited my post.

Comment: Okay, sorry I dont know how to answer this now.